# Get post content respecting pagination Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I am using this hook to get the content of a page and display it using pagination on startup.

```
get_the_content_by_id( $mobile_content );
```

The problem is that he doesn't respect me

```
<!--nextpage-->
```

What would be the appropriate hook for me to respect the pagination?

**I am currently using it like this but I think it is not the right option**

```
$mobile_content = 2525; //id post or page
$pagina = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
$shortcodebyid = get_the_content_by_id( $mobile_content );
$shortcodebyid = explode('<!--nextpage-->', $shortcodebyid);
echo $shortcodebyid[($pagina - 1)];
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: `echo get_the_content($pagina);`